# Appengine model property docstring

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-sphinx

I'm using several appengine models and autodoc.  However I can't find any
way of getting my documentation for attributes to apply.  I am using [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) and building the doc with [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/).

For example with the model:

```
class Greeting(ndb.Model):
  """Models an individual Guestbook entry with content and date."""
  content = ndb.StringProperty()
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

The resulting docstring for content is

> An indexed Property whose value is a text string of limited length

I have tried the following approaches:

```
  "The content"
  content = ndb.StringProperty()

  content = ndb.StringProperty()
  "The content"

  #: the content
  content = ndb.StringProperty()

  content = ndb.StringProperty()
  content.__doc__="The content"

  content = ndb.StringProperty(__doc__="the content")

  content = ndb.StringProperty(doc="the content")
```

None of them give an error, or work - I always get "An indexed Property ...".  I'm surprised
explicitly setting __doc__ had no effect.

Any idea how to get my own docstring used?

Comment: Not an expert on Sphinx, but I would expect that you would document the fields in the class docstring itself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is normal to document fields where they occur in the code.  It works for regular classes.

Comment: Really? Not in any doc format I've ever used. I can't show it in a comment, but as an example see the [Google Python open-source style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments) (scroll down a bit to get to the Classes subsection) where they include an Attributes section inside the class-level docstring.

Comment: Sphinx really does let you document attributes using doc strings.  The problem in this case was pebkac, and two different syntaxes work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Sphinx works just fine.  I was looking at the wrong copy of the doc output that hadn't been rebuilt.  Both of these work:

```
content = ndb.StringProperty()
"The content"

#: the content
content = ndb.StringProperty()
```